# Coap.Net - Starting

Tags: c#, coap

I'm currently trying to start with CoAP in C#. The library I'm using is CoAP.Net (→ https://github.com/smeshlink/CoAP.NET).

Unfortunately, I didn't even succeed with the example published in the "Quick Start"-Section on GitHub.

My Server Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CoapServer server = new CoapServer();
        server.Add(new HelloWorldRessouce());
        server.Start();
    }
}
```

and a ressource-class in the Server solution:

```
class HelloWorldRessouce : CoAP.Server.Resources.Resource
{
    public HelloWorldRessouce() : base("hello-world")
    {
        Attributes.Title = "GET a friendly greeting!";
    }

    protected override void DoGet (CoapExchange exchange)
    {
        exchange.Respond("Hello World fron CoAP.NET!");
    }
}
```

On the client-side I've got the following:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CoapClient client = new CoapClient();

        Request request = new Request(Method.GET);
        //request.URI = new Uri("coap://[::1]/hello-world");
        request.URI = new Uri("coap://192.168.178.48:5683/hello-world");
        request.Send();

        // wait for response
        Response response = request.WaitForResponse();
    }
```

Here is the Console-Output from the Server:

> DEBUG - Starting CoAP server
>
> DEBUG - BlockwiseLayer uses MaxMessageSize: 1024 and
>   DefaultBlockSize:512
>
> DBEUG - Starting endpoint bound to [::ffff:0:0]:5683
>
> Press any key...

Here is the Console-Output from the Client:
[Console-Output - Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvs1P.png)

I'm pretty sure, the problems are on the Client-side...

It would be awesome, if there's someone to help me get this example running. Or maybe, someone can give me a few Noob-Examples. The example-files don't really help me with this problem...

Thanks everybody...
Cheers, Mirco

Comment: Hi Michal, thanks for answering.
Indeed, the server is listening on an IPv6-address. But if I'm using the line
 --> request.URI = new Uri("coap://[::1]/hello-world");
there's still the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it seems as if there was the dumbest user at work...^^

Server-side:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CoapServer server = new CoapServer();
    server.Add(new HelloWorldRessouce());
    server.Start();
}
```

after "server.Start();" the program is finished and the server turns off.

By adding a "Console.ReadKey();" afterwards, everything is fine.

If someone has any noob-examples espacially about the configuration, they are still appreciated.

Thanks everybody ;)